# How to setup a proper storage for published documents to the public?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a huge content database in size, the size of the content DB is more than 16 GB, and this content DB is associated with a web application that is exposed to the public on the internet, there are occasions where I get heavy visitor hits on the site, and those visitors will download a PDF, or a Word document, so I need to separate those documents to be stored in another place not on the same content database of the public site.

I don't want to use the Remote BLOB Storage, I need to have like a DMS solution or another SharePoint site collection to store the documents in it (as physical files) and integrate it with a document library in the public site.

Is there a way to acheive this?

**Note: The site is created on top of SharePoint 2013**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16 GB is not considered huge for a SharePoint database.  In general you are going to be OK until your DB hits 200+ GB, I've worked with DBs in the 750 GB range in SP2013 before.  Content Databases hold Site collections, you can't split a site collection into two different databases, so the only way to achieve this would be to create a new site collection in a new database.  This site collection would obviously have a different URL than the one currently in use.  So if your users are hitting yoursite/sites/site1 and you want to store these documents in a different DB, you would need to setup yoursite/sites/site2 in a new DB, then provide links on site1 that point to the documents in site2. This is a lot to setup, and maintain in the future as new documents are added new links will need to be added.  Since you are only at 16 GB now I would not do this unless you expect a large amount of growth.